# uva C++11 and C++ gives runtime error while every uDebug data is correct

Tags: c++

I am doing [UVA 10226 Hardwood Species](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1167). To avoid using gets, I use fgets to detect empty line. If there's anything I missed please let me know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    map<string,int> mp;
    char c,str[105];
    scanf("%d\n",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        mp.clear();
        int total=0;
        while(fgets(str,100,stdin),strlen(str)>1){
            total++;
            *strchr(str,'\n')='\0';
            string tmp(str);
            if(mp.find(tmp)==mp.end())mp[tmp]=1;
            else mp[tmp]++;
        }
        for(map<string,int>::iterator it=mp.begin();it!=mp.end();it++){
            printf("%s %.4lf\n",it->first.c_str(),(double)(it->second)/total*100.);
        }
        if(i<n-1)
            puts("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not the problem but `if(mp.find(tmp)==mp.end())mp[tmp]=1;
            else mp[tmp]++;` can be replaced with just `mp[tmp]++;`

Comment: Any reason you're not using `std::getline` ? Your code is more C than C++.

Comment: This is also a prime candidate for invoking undefined behavior if any line (specifically, the last line) does *not* end with a `'\n'`, which is more common than you may think.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen I'm more familiar with c-style input because school taught it first.

Comment: To do this with the C++ standard library and its offerings would look [something like this](https://pastebin.com/Z3zE5kgh).

Comment: And in C++17, you can expand the map iteration direction in the for `for (auto &&[first, second] : mp) { .. } `

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for your example. I changed my code to `while(getline(cin,str)&&str.length())` and uva accepted.